# Method of one class not executing when called form a different class

Tags: objective-c, object

I am working on a front end for a project in objective-c and I am having some trouble getting methods of my class `Window` which is a subclass of `NSViewController` to fully execute when called from a different class.

I have a method of the class `Window` that is called `setColor` which changes the color of my `NSTableView` variable which is linked to a bordered scroll view in my interface. I am able to successfully change the color by calling the `setColor` method like this from the init method in `Window`: `[self  setColor :self];`

However when I do this `[window1 setColor: window1]` with `window1` being an object of the class `Window` that I have declared in class `Door`, nothing seems to happen since the color of the boarded scroll view remains the same.

My `Window.h` file looks like this:

```
@interface Window : NSViewController {


   @public

        IBOutlet NSTableView *dataTableView;


}

 @property (retain) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;


- (IBAction)SetColor:(id)sender;
@end
```

My `Window.m` looks like this:

```
@synthesize tableView;

 - (void) awakeFromNib {

//  [self  SetColor :self];

}

- (IBAction)SetColor:(id)sender;
{


    NSLog(@"changing the color");
    [self->tableView  setBackgroundColor: NSColor.blueColor];

}
```

`Door.h` looks like this

```
@interface Door : NSViewController {

   Window* window1;

}

-(IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender;

@property (retain) Window* window1;
@end
```

`Door.m` looks like this:

```
-(void) dealloc{
    [window1 release];
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
      window1 = [Window alloc];
    }

-(IBAction)buttonPress :(id)Sender;
{
      [window1 setColor: window1];
}
```

I am using Xcode 3.2 so I cannot use ARC.

Comment: Why are you using such a vastly outdated version of Xcode? Your are wasting your time learning such old, outdated tools.

Comment: You need to study the basics of Objective-C (so you won't say `alloc` without saying `init`). Then you need to learn what a nib is and how it gets loaded and what an outlet is in relation to this. _Then_ you can get into windows and view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

`window1 = [Window alloc]` will not load a Nib or storyboard and connect the outlet `IBOutlet NSTableView *dataTableView` to the table view inside it.

If "Window" is a view controller, you need to initialize it and the outlets in it a more standard way.  View controllers need the proper initialization or the outlets are nil, and in Objective-C, if you send a method to nil, it just does nothing.

Comment: It's much worse than that. Saying `alloc` without also saying `init` is wrong, illegal, and stupid.

Comment: Yeah, there is more wrong here-- like using Xcode 3.2-- but you can only say so much.  I also didn't want to imply that `init` would fix anything, because just-plain-init on the VC is not right, either.

Comment: How do I properly initialize it? `[[Window alloc] init]` does not fix my problem.

Comment: There are several possible ways.  Are you using a storyboard?  Nibs?  Have you ever made a basic iOS app?  Have you gone through a tutorial?